# circular dependency QThread

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, client-server, circular-dependency

I have a task to create a chess game with support for network play.
For development I've been using Qt.
The problem is as follows:
I have class "MyServer":
Header file->

```
//Header file "MyServer.h"    
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <mythread.h>
#include <QDebug>

class MyServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void startServer();
    QList<QString> *usersOnline;
    QList<QTcpSocket*> *connections;


signals:

public slots:
protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);


private:
    QTcpServer* server;
    //QTcpSocket* socket;

    //QByteArray* bytes;
    //QString* str;

};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

cpp.file

```
#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,1234);
    usersOnline=new QList<QString>;

}
void  MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    MyThread* thread=new MyThread(socketDescriptor,this,this);
    thread->run();
}
```

As you can see, this class with a new connection creates a new thread.
Class "MyThread".
Header file

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QObject>
#include <myserver.h>

class MyServer;
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int ID,MyServer* s,QObject *parent = 0);

    void run();

signals:

public slots:
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket* socket;


    int socketDescriptor;
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

cpp.file

```
#include "mythread.h"


MyThread::MyThread(int ID,MyServer* s,QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    //this->mainserver=parent;


    //parent=new MyServer();
    //qDebug()<<s->usersOnline;



    this->socketDescriptor=ID;

}



void MyThread::run()
{

    qDebug()<<"Starts thread";
    socket=new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    exec();
}

void MyThread::readyRead()
{
   QDataStream in(this->socket);

    quint32 n;
    in>>n;
    qDebug()<<n;
    QByteArray bytes;
   QDataStream out(&bytes,QIODevice::WriteOnly);;
   QString str;

    switch (n) {
   case 1:

       in>>str;
       qDebug()<<str;
        //usersOnline->append(str);
        //qDebug()<<*(usersOnline);


        //out(&bytes,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        //out<<(*usersOnline);




      //for(int i=0;i<this->connections->length();i++)
        //{
            //connections->at(i)->is
            //connections->at(i)->write(bytes);
            //connections->at(i)->waitForBytesWritten(2000);
       // }
        break;
   case 2:

        in>>str;
        qDebug()<<str;
        break;
    }
}
```

In "MyThread" constructor i pass pointer to "MyServer" class to use the fields "usersOnline","connections" and "MyServer" method.

Thus, i have in my architecture "circular dependency" with "MyServer" and "MyThread" class.
How to change architecture?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a side note: QThread is used for managing threads, not for processing data. You should subclass QObject instead. Read [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20691) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `#include <myserver.h>` from your thread header. You already have `class MyServer;` forward definition there, it will be enough.

Comment: Question was: How to change architecture?

Comment: Well, you can just remove `MyServer* s` argument from the constructor. You don't use it anyway. If you need to use this pointer in the thread, use forward definition, the architecture is fine. If you don't need to use it, don't use it. If you want to use it but without circular dependency, you should have posted real `MyThread` code that uses `MyServer` pointer. Without that code no one can tell you how to change architecture because there is in fact no dependency, only an unused pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Riateche, but as you can see in "MyThread" cpp file i used pointer to "MyServer"  //qDebug()<<s->usersOnline

Comment: It's commented out and it's just a debug output. I don't know why you really need `usersOnline` here. You can just move this debug statement to `MyServer` class to eliminate the reference! In this the answer you want? Also, as pointed in comments, you shouldn't subclass QThread at all. And `QThread::start` should be used to start a thread, not `QThread::run`. But all these issues has nothing to do with circular references.

Comment: **usersOnline** must be in **MyServer** because when **user** disconnected,current thread with this connection must send all online users(information about online users located in **s->connections**) that one user is disconnected

Comment: I didn't say you need to move `usersOnline` somewhere else.